# Angular2 - Ag Grid - Get Parent Instance in Cell Renderer Component

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid

I am using Ag Grid for displaying a list of items in my Project.
I have implemented Ag Grid with colDef for grid as like below

**custom.component.ts**

**CustomComponent**

//colum definition array

```
[
             {
                headerName: "Actions", 
                field: "action", 
                width: 100,
                cellRendererFramework: ActionRendererComponent,
            },
]
```

**ActionRendererComponent**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {AgRendererComponent} from 'ag-grid-ng2/main';

@Component({
    selector: 'action-cell',
    template: `
    <a href="javascript:" *ngIf="showEditLink" (click)="edit()">&nbsp;&nbsp;Edit</a>
    <a href="javascript:" *ngIf="showSaveLink" (click)="save()">&nbsp;&nbsp;Save</a>
    <a href="javascript:" *ngIf="showCancelLink" (click)="cancel()">Cancel</a>
    `
})

export class ActionRendererComponent implements AgRendererComponent {
 public edit(){
  ..some logic here
 }
 public save(){
  ..some logic here
 }
 public cancel(){
  ..some logic here
 }
}
```

Now the issue is i cannot get access to parent instance CustomComponent
in any of the functions in **ActionRenderer** like save(), edit(), cancel().
How can i pass parent instance into **ActionRenderer** component?

Comment: I am running into the exact same problem, have you had any luck yet?

Answer (score 14):

In your parent component while initializing the grid make sure you add following code in its constructor:

```
import {GridOptions} from "ag-grid";
constructor(){ 
    this.gridOptions = <GridOptions>{
        context: {
            componentParent: this
        }
    };
}
```

In your template make sure you include gridOptions

```
<ag-grid-angular #agGrid [gridOptions]="gridOptions">
```

Make sure you follow steps above. In your cell renderer component, try logging the params. You should be able to get this.params.context.componentParent.

For further reference: [Ag-grid parent-child](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-more-details/#parent_child)

Answer (score 2):

Do these

1. Add `context: { componentParent: this }` property to `gridOptions`
2. Use `this.params.context.componentParent` in `ActionRendererComponent`

Refer to source code of child-message.component given [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering/?framework=angular#gsc.tab=0)

Regards.

Comment: @mkl He is giving an answer, the link is only used as a reference.

Comment: @NahuelIanni The first sentence alone would be a candidate for "This is a comment, not an answer."

Comment: @mkl Not according to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)

Comment: @NahuelIanni That meta answer (in combination with the votes for it) indeed indicates that answers like this according to majority consensus should be considered answers. Nonetheless the answer should be improved for general usefulness.

Comment: @mkl Yes, I agree with that :)

Answer (score 0):

in my cell renderer I was able to use `params.eParentOfValue` to then apply some CSS styles to the outer cell