# Ag grid on button click open a pop up and pass data from row in pop up in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs, popup, ag-grid

I am using ag-grid in angular and in each row on the last column, I have an icon after clicking on which a pop up should open and Edit, Delete and Add functions are displayed which should have id and some other data passed from row data. I am using a different component for edit, delete and add functions. When I am clicking on the Invoke Parent button the subcomponent is not opening and I am trying to figure out what am I missing? I am using [How to add pop up on ag-grid data in angular 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54163266/how-to-add-pop-up-on-ag-grid-data-in-angular-6) as a refernce

manage.component.html

```
<ag-grid-angular
  style="padding-top: 10px;" 
  class="ag-theme-alpine"
  [rowData]="rowData" 
  [columnDefs]="columnDefs" 
  (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
   [pagination]="true" 
  [paginationPageSize]="5"
  [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"  
  [frameworkComponents]="frameworkComponents"
  domLayout="autoHeight" 
>
</ag-grid-angular>
```

manage.component.ts

```
export class ManageComponent implements OnInit {
      public frameworkComponents : any;

      constructor(private myService: MyService) {
        this.frameworkComponents = {
          actionItemCellRenderer: ActionItemComponent,
        };
    
      }
 public columnDefs: ColDef[] = [
           .
           .
           .
          {
          headerName: 'Actions',
          field: 'id',
          cellRenderer: 'actionItemCellRenderer',
          cellStyle: {
            borderRightColor: '#e1e1e1',
            borderRightWidth: '1px',
            borderRightStyle: 'solid',
          },
        },];

       public methodFromParent() {
          console.log('methodFromParent is called');
          this.openMyDialogPopUp();
        }
        public openMyDialogPopUp() {
            const eDiv = document.createElement('div');
            var plusiconhtml = '<i class="icon--plus-add" style="color:#0672CB; margin-right: 10px;padding-right:10px" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
            var editiconhtml = '<i class="icon--pencil" style="color:#0672CB; margin-right: 10px;padding-right:10px" aria-hidden="true"></i>'
            var trashiconhtml = '<i class="icon--trash" style="color:red; margin-right: 10px;padding-right:10px" aria-hidden="true"></i>'
            eDiv.innerHTML = plusiconhtml + editiconhtml + trashiconhtml;
            
            const createIcon = eDiv.querySelectorAll('.icon--plus-add')[0];
            createIcon.addEventListener('click', () => {
              window.location.href = '/create-sample?id=' + 5;
            });
            return eDiv;
        }
```

popup.component.html

```
<span>
    <button style="height: 20px" (click)="invokeParentMethod()" class="btn btn-info">
        Invoke Parent
    </button>
</span>
```

popup.component.ts

```
import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {ICellRendererAngularComp} from "ag-grid-angular";
@Component({
  selector: 'app-popup',
  templateUrl: './popup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./popup.component.css']
})
export class PopupComponent implements ICellRendererAngularComp  {
  public params: any;
    
  agInit(params: any): void {
    this.params = params;
  }
    
  public invokeParentMethod() {
    debugger;
    this.params.context.componentParent.methodFromParent(`Row: ${this.params.node.rowIndex}, Col: ${this.params.colDef.headerName}`)
  }
    
  refresh(): boolean {
    return false;
  }

}
```

Comment: If you could make a plunker or stackblitz it would be much easier to help you debug

Comment: Can you show us how you are passing the componentParent object in the context?  Do you mean the console.log in the method methodFromParent  is getting called but the next line is not working?

Comment: it seems like openMyDialogPopUp is not working, so I am not sure that is the things I am missing